# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7. Why is this happening?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

Code for adaptor:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class quotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<quotesAdapter.quotesViewHolder> {

    private List<String> quotes;
    private List<String> authors;
    private List<ImageView> images = null;
    private Context context;

    public quotesAdapter(List<String> quotes, QuotesActivity quotesActivity, List<String> authors, Context context) {
        this.quotes = quotes;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public quotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_item_quotes, viewGroup, false);

//        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item_quotes, parent, false);
//        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        return new quotesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull quotesViewHolder holder, int i) {
        String[] colors = {"#952222", "#10171B", "#FF373535", "#ECE3D3", "#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B","#10171B"};
        String quote = quotes.get(i);
        ***String author = authors.get(i);***
        holder.txtQuote.setText(quote);
        holder.txtAuthor.setText(author);
        int color = i % colors.length;
        int intColor = Color.parseColor(colors[color]);
        holder.quoteContainer.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
        holder.txtQuote.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
        holder.txtAuthor.setBackgroundColor(intColor);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return quotes.size();
    }

    public static class quotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtQuote;
        TextView txtAuthor;
        LinearLayout quoteContainer;

        public quotesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtQuote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuote);
            txtAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthor);
            quoteContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quotesContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for activity:

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class QuotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quotes_act);
        RecyclerView quotesList = findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
        quotesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        quotesList.setAdapter(new quotesAdapter(getQuotes(), this,getAuthors(),this));
    }

    private List<String> getQuotes() {
        List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("quotes.txt"), "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                quotes.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return quotes;
    }

    private List<String> getAuthors() {
        List<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("authors.txt"), "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                authors.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return authors;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: konak.labs.warstoriesv2, PID: 820
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at konak.labs.warstoriesv2.quotesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(quotesAdapter.java:47)
        at konak.labs.warstoriesv2.quotesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(quotesAdapter.java:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:286)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:343)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:359)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:366)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:397)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The quotes.txt and authors.txt are inside the res folder of my project. Also, the app does show the first few instances of getAuthors and getQuotes but crashes after showing these. I dont know why it crashes. Maybe if i throw an exception into my adaptor code to handle when there is no more items to view. But the crash happens when the authors is included in the adaptor code. I removed the authors list from being populated in the recyclerview and the quotes did correctly display without crash, even if there was nothing left to display (no more quotes).

Any help guys?

Comment: Your `Adapter` is saying that it has `quotes.size()` number of items, and you apparently have more quotes than authors. That's a risk you take when you use multiple separate lists like that.

Comment: Yep thats true. How to incorporate both files into one and separate quotes and their corresponding authors together?

Comment: I don't know that I can really answer that, because I have no idea how those lists correspond to each other. It seems odd that you'd have those in two separate files to begin with. If I were doing this, everything would be in one file, perhaps with one quote and its author on each line. Then I'd make a `Quote` class that has a `String text;` and `String author;` fields in it, and use a single `List<Quote>` everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Index begins from 0. Therefore, for an array of size 7, the index will be from 0 to 6.**

- If the **index is 0**, then it refers to the **1st element** of the array.
- If the **index is 1**, then it refers to the **2nd element**.
- ...

The error

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7`

signifies that

The array has only 7 elements, but an attempt was made to extract the 8th element.